# TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Request' with elastic.js

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

**i tried the following sample code:**

```
var es=require("elasticsearch");
var ejs = require("ejs");


var client = new es.Client({
  host: 'localhost:9200',
  log: 'trace'
});


client.ping({
  requestTimeout: 3000,

  // undocumented params are appended to the query string
  hello: "elasticsearch"
}, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
  } else {
    console.log('All is well');
  }
});

client.search({
  index: 'message-1',
  type: 'message',
  body: ejs.Request().query(ejs.MatchAllQuery())
}).then(function (resp) {
  var hits = resp.hits.hits;
}, function (err) {
  console.trace(err.message);
});
```

**i am getting the following error when i try to run: node metric.js**

```
/home/karunakar/test/metricagg/metric.js:27
  body: ejs.Request().query(ejs.MatchAllQuery())
            ^
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Request'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/karunakar/test/metricagg/metric.js:27:13)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

i could not locate the problem. 
-- Thanks

Comment: I'm not very familiar with ejs, but I can't find `ejs.Request()` anywhere in the documentation.

Comment: @jmar777 : Thanks.. could you give some sample code to prepare aggregate query with elastic.js module.

Answer (score 0):

You want the [`elastic.js`](https://github.com/fullscale/elastic.js/) module and not [`ejs`](https://github.com/mde/ejs), which is a templating engine module.

Comment: i tried with elastic.js module also. i am getting the same error.

Comment: You mean you tried `var ejs = require("elastic.js");` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the first `require("elasticsearch")` but the second one should be `require("elastic.js")` instead of `require("ejs")`